# phonagep ios app xhr reponse null

Tags: ios, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have developed a phonegap app with xmhttprequest to get some text from the web. It works fine in android, but it is not working in iOS.

Here are the problems:

1. In index.html, I include external resource of jquery mobile. It's not working.
2. xmlhttprequest response is null, but status=200. Neither success nor error function be called.

I have :

1. cordova 3.9.1
2. access origin="*"
   allow-navigation href="*"

What should I do?

Comment: Which versions of Cordova and iOS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Agnes,
this is a mixed answer. On Cordove/Phonegap versions before 4.0.0, `whitelist` is NOT required, neither is the new requirement of CSP(Content Security Policy). However as of iOS9, Apple has a new ATS (App Transport Security) that is being enforced.

I don't have a good answer for you because the current Cordova `whitelist` documentation is mess. My [raw notes](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-system.md) show the confusion. I'm still sorting it out for blog post.

The best that I can do is turn you towards the clean FAQ
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Read **10. Not adding the new "white-list", "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml AND "Content Security Policy"**

The Apple stuff is at the bottom of that section.
Please let me know what you figure out.

TIA

Comment: Thanks! It helps to solve the issue. I add the NSAppTransportSecurity to my ios-Info.plist.